# Gulp js is only packaging the last .less file it finds

Tags: gulp, gulp-sass, gulp-uglify

I have a project which hasn't had a new code commit in about 1year. Recently, a build was triggered for said project (underlying build agent orchestration was changed, the build chain appears to be properly reestablished), and the result was that every `.less` file is ignored entirely *except for the last one it finds*

the expected behavior is all `.less` files are bundled, as they have been for the last several years.

What could cause this?

things ive already done/reviewed:

- package version changes
- code changes (nothing for the last year)

Demonstrable symptom : rename the "only found" `.less` file to something other than `.less` and it will "only find" the prior `.less` file

Has any one experienced this?

edit: Here are the `.less` related tasks

```
 gulp.task('styles', function () {
    var lessOptions = {
        options: [
            options.src + '/app'
        ]
    };

    var injectFiles = gulp.src([
        options.src + '/app/**/*.less',
        '!' + options.src + '/app/index.less',
        '!' + options.src + '/app/vendor.less'
    ], {read: false});

    var injectOptions = {
        transform: function (filePath) {
            filePath = filePath.replace(options.src + '/app/', '');
            return '@import \'' + filePath + '\';';
        },
        starttag: '// injector',
        endtag: '// endinjector',
        addRootSlash: false
    };

    var indexFilter = $.filter('index.less', {restore: true});
    var vendorFilter = $.filter('vendor.less', {restore: true});

    return gulp.src([
            options.src + '/app/index.less',
            options.src + '/app/vendor.less'
        ])
        .pipe(indexFilter)
        .pipe($.inject(injectFiles, injectOptions))
        .pipe(indexFilter.restore)
        .pipe(vendorFilter)
        .pipe(wiredep(_.extend({}, options.wiredep)))
        .pipe(vendorFilter.restore)
        .pipe($.sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe($.less(lessOptions)).on('error', options.errorHandler('Less'))
        .pipe($.autoprefixer()).on('error', options.errorHandler('Autoprefixer'))
        .pipe($.sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(options.tmp + '/serve/app/'))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}));
});
```

Comment: Please add the relevant tasks of your gulpfile to the question.

Comment: @TheDancingCode - updated less related task(s)